# EmptyView of ListView hides BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, listview, bottomnavigationview

I have an AppCompatActivity with a listview with the layout below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/user_title"
            android:background="@drawable/user_title_color"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"/>
    <ListView android:id="@+id/joggings_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="#b5b5b5"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_list"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center">
            <TextView
                android:text="No joggings yet"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/empty_add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_jogging"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
        app:borderWidth="0dp" />
        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:foregroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
            app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
            app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and in my code I have 
        **mListView.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty_list));**

in order to display a message and an "add" button when the list is empty.  My problem is that when the list is empty the BottomNavigationView is hidden and the user cannot navigate to another activity.
One possible solution I can think of is to add another BottomNavigationView with the same items in the empty layout but that seems ugly.

Any other solution?

Comment: Seems to be a layout order problem, your BottomNavigationView is pulled off from the screen, so a possible solution is to use a relative layout as a direct sibling of the coordinator, to ensure that all the views will fit the screen.

Answer (score 1):

Set empty_list height to wrap_content

Comment: This worked, but textbox and button of empty list are displayed at the top of the screen and  the bottomNavigationView is displayed right under them.  I would like to center vertically the empty layout and display bottomNavigationView to the bottom of the screen

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center" add this

Answer (score 1):

Your `ListView` and it's empty view should have the same layout attributes if you want them to occupy the same space. In your case, they should both be

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Also, you should put the `FloatingActionButton` *outside* of the `LinearLayout`, or else it will affect the size of your `ListView`/empty view. It is also meant to be a direct child of `CoordinatorLayout`, otherwise its default behaviors do not work.

Comment: Putting FloatingActionButton as direct child of CoordinatorLayout hides part of FloatingActionButton under BottomNavigationView

Comment: Check their elevations. Also, I suggest either moving the FAB or getting rid of it entirely, because the bottom of your screen will be cluttered if you have both that and the BottomNavigationView.

Answer (score 0):

The following layout worked fine.  The basic idea is that coordinateLayout contains listview and FloatingActionButton and empty view. CoordinateLayout is contained in an outer vertical LinearLayout which also contains the header textview and the BottomNavigationView

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/user_title_color"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/main_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/joggings_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:divider="#b5b5b5"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/add_jogging"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_navigation"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_plus"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/joggings_list"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/empty_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No joggings yet" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/empty_add_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Add" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:foregroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
</LinearLayout>
```